# Delphi XE 7 project template for saving / loading form settings

Tags: form, delphi

I have developed small test project as a template for production project.
In this template I've found a way that the application saves and loads its own settings (ini-file). 
Main **Form1** will contain many other sub-forms **Form2**, **Form3**, ... **FormN**

Each sub-form has its own settings, but only main form is responsible for saving/loading settings for these forms (sub-forms only can give an access to settings via public methods). In this example I've introduced only **Form2** for simplicity.

I need your comments and advice about my method.
The project is developed in Delphi XE 7.

[Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/asnpv8alasl91p5/Test_Project_Novichok_OOP.zip)

```
program Project_Test_Application;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  U_Common in 'U_Common.pas',
  U_Singleton in 'U_Singleton.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;

  P_MAIN_START;

     Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);

     Form1.P_START;

     Application.Run;

  P_MAIN_EXIT;


end.






unit U_Common;

interface

uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,  Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
     U_Singleton, Unit2;



{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function  F_GS: TSingleton;
procedure P_MAIN_START;
procedure P_MAIN_EXIT;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure P_DS(const S : String);


implementation  uses Unit1;


{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function F_GS: TSingleton;
begin
      F_GS := F_Singleton;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure P_MAIN_START;
begin
     P_Singleton_MAIN_START;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure P_MAIN_EXIT;
begin
     P_Singleton_MAIN_EXIT;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure P_DS(const S : String);
var W : PWideChar;
begin
   W := PWideChar(S);
   OutputDebugString(W);
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}


end.






unit U_Singleton;

interface
uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
     Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, IniFiles;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
type TSingleton = class

strict private

            FF_Destroying            : Boolean  ;
            FF_Application_Directory : String   ;
            FF_Main_Exit             : BOOLEAN  ;
            O_INI                    : TIniFile ;

            procedure   P_Internal_Start;

            procedure   P_Get_Application_Directory;
            procedure   P_Prepare_INI_File_Storage;

private

            constructor InternalCreate;
            procedure   InternalDestroy;

            procedure   P_Declare_Main_Exit;

public

            constructor Create;
            destructor  Destroy; override;
            procedure   BeforeDestruction; override;

            procedure   Write_Integer(const Parameter_Name : String; const x             : Integer);
            function    Read_Integer (const Parameter_Name : String; const Value_if_Null : Integer) : Integer;

            procedure   Write_String (const Parameter_Name : String; const x             :  String);
            function    Read_String  (const Parameter_Name : String; const Value_if_Null :  String) : String;

            function    F_App_Dir(const s_File_Name : String) : String;

            property    Application_Directory : String  read FF_Application_Directory ;
            property    Main_Exit             : BOOLEAN read FF_Main_Exit;

            const c_INI_File_Name = 'Settings.ini';
                  c_INI_Section   = 'Application';

end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function  F_Singleton : TSingleton;
procedure P_Singleton_MAIN_START;
procedure P_Singleton_MAIN_EXIT;

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

implementation var GS : TSingleton;


{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure P_Singleton_MAIN_START;
begin
  OutputDebugString('procedure P_MAIN_START ');
  GS := nil;
  GS := F_Singleton;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure P_Singleton_MAIN_EXIT;
begin
  OutputDebugString('procedure P_MAIN_EXIT ');
  if GS <> nil then
  begin
    GS.P_Declare_Main_Exit;
    GS.InternalDestroy;
    GS := nil;
  end;
  //----Application.Terminate;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}



{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function F_Singleton: TSingleton;
begin
  if GS = nil then  GS := TSingleton.InternalCreate;
  Result := GS;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  if not FF_Destroying then raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Do not call TSingleton.Destroy');
  inherited;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
constructor TSingleton.Create;
begin
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Do not call TSingleton.Create');
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
constructor TSingleton.InternalCreate;
begin
  inherited Create;
  P_Internal_Start;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.InternalDestroy;
begin
  FF_Destroying := True;
  Destroy;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
destructor TSingleton.Destroy;
begin
  // your cleanup
  O_INI.Free;

  inherited;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.P_Internal_Start;
begin
     P_Get_Application_Directory;
     P_Prepare_INI_File_Storage;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.P_Get_Application_Directory;
begin
      FF_Application_Directory := IncludeTrailingBackslash(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function TSingleton.F_App_Dir(const s_File_Name: string) : String;
begin
      Result := FF_Application_Directory + s_File_Name;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.P_Prepare_INI_File_Storage;
begin
       O_INI:=TIniFile.Create(F_App_Dir(c_INI_File_Name));
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.P_Declare_Main_Exit;
begin
       FF_Main_Exit:=True;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.Write_Integer(const Parameter_Name: string; const x: Integer);
begin
      try O_INI.WriteInteger(c_INI_Section,Parameter_Name,x) except end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function TSingleton.Read_Integer(const Parameter_Name: string; const Value_if_Null: Integer) : Integer;
begin
              Result := Value_if_Null;
        try   Result := O_INI.ReadInteger(c_INI_Section,Parameter_Name,Value_if_Null); except end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TSingleton.Write_String(const Parameter_Name: string; const x: String);
begin
        try O_INI.WriteString(c_INI_Section,Parameter_Name,x) except end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function TSingleton.Read_String(const Parameter_Name: string; const Value_if_Null: String) : String;
begin
              Result := Value_if_Null;
        try   Result := O_INI.ReadString(c_INI_Section,Parameter_Name,Value_if_Null); except end;
end;
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}



end.





unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  U_Common, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PC_Main: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    Tab_Exit: TTabSheet;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure PC_MainChange(Sender: TObject);
  private

    procedure P_Create_Event_Log_Form ;
    procedure P_INI_Parameters_Save   ;
    procedure P_INI_Parameters_Load   ;

  const

    c_P_Font_Name = 'Event_Log_Font_Name';
    c_P_Font_Size = 'Event_Log_Font_Size';

  public

    F_FRM_Event_Log : TForm2;

    procedure P_START;
    procedure P_END;

  end;

var  Form1: TForm1;


implementation
{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
      CanClose := False;
      P_END;
      CanClose := True;
end;


procedure TForm1.P_START;
begin
       ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True ;
       P_Create_Event_Log_Form             ;
       P_INI_Parameters_Load               ;
       PC_Main.ActivePageIndex := TabSheet1.PageIndex ;
end;


procedure TForm1.P_END;
begin
      P_INI_Parameters_Save         ;
end;


procedure TForm1.P_INI_Parameters_Save ;
begin
 if F_FRM_Event_Log.F_We_Must_Save_Font_Size  then  F_GS.Write_Integer( F_FRM_Event_Log.PAR_Font_Size, F_FRM_Event_Log.F_Current_Font_Size ) ;
 if F_FRM_Event_Log.F_We_Must_Save_Font_Name  then  F_GS.Write_String ( F_FRM_Event_Log.PAR_Font_Name, F_FRM_Event_Log.F_Current_Font_Name ) ;
end;


procedure TForm1.P_INI_Parameters_Load ;
         var i:Integer; S:String;

         procedure P_Font_Size;
         begin
          i:=F_GS.Read_Integer(F_FRM_Event_Log.PAR_Font_Size,F_FRM_Event_Log.C_Error_Font_Size);
          F_FRM_Event_Log.P_Try_to_Set_Font_Size(i);
          F_FRM_Event_Log.P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Size(i);
         end;

         procedure P_Font_Name;
         begin
          S:=F_GS.Read_String(F_FRM_Event_Log.PAR_Font_Name,F_FRM_Event_Log.C_Error_Font_Name);
          F_FRM_Event_Log.P_Try_to_Set_Font_Name(S);
          F_FRM_Event_Log.P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Name(S);
         end;
begin
      P_Font_Size;
      P_Font_Name;
end;



procedure TForm1.PC_MainChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
        if PC_Main.ActivePageIndex = Tab_Exit.PageIndex then Close;
end;


procedure TForm1.P_Create_Event_Log_Form;
begin
      Application.CreateForm(TForm2, F_FRM_Event_Log);
      F_FRM_Event_Log.Parent      := Panel1;
      F_FRM_Event_Log.Align       := alClient;
      F_FRM_Event_Log.Visible     := True;
      F_FRM_Event_Log.Caption     := '' ;
      F_FRM_Event_Log.BorderStyle := bsNone ;
end;




end.









unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TForm2 = class(TForm)

    Memo1: TMemo;
    cb_Font_Name: TComboBox;
    cb_Font_Size: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

    const

    C_Error_Font_Name = '';
    C_Error_Font_Size = 0;

    C_Font_Min = 8;
    C_Font_Max = 20;

    procedure Action_Font_Size(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Action_Font_Name(Sender: TObject);

  strict private

            Default_Font_Name     : String       ;
            Default_Font_Size     : Integer      ;

            Last_Loaded_Font_Name : String       ;
            Last_Loaded_Font_Size : Integer      ;

            procedure P_Make_List_of_Font_Name;
            procedure P_Make_List_of_Font_Size;
            procedure P_Init_Default_Values;

            procedure P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Name(const B_Activate:BOOLEAN);
            procedure P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Size(const B_Activate:BOOLEAN);

            procedure P_Start    ;


  public
            const

            PAR_Font_Name = 'Event_Log_Font_Name';
            PAR_Font_Size = 'Event_Log_Font_Size';

            function  F_Current_Font_Size : Integer ;
            function  F_Current_Font_Name : String  ;

            function  F_We_Must_Save_Font_Size : BOOLEAN;
            function  F_We_Must_Save_Font_Name : BOOLEAN;

            procedure P_Try_to_Set_Font_Size  (const i_Font_Size : Integer);
            procedure P_Try_to_Set_Font_Name  (const s_Font_Name : String );

            procedure P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Size  (const i_Font_Size : Integer);
            procedure P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Name  (const s_Font_Name : String );

  end;



implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.P_Start;

      procedure P_Set_Font;
      begin
           P_Init_Default_Values      ;

           P_Make_List_of_Font_Name ;
           P_Make_List_of_Font_Size ;

           P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Name(True);
           P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Size(True);

           P_Try_To_Set_Font_Name(F_Current_Font_Name);
           P_Try_To_Set_Font_Size(F_Current_Font_Size);
      end;

begin
      P_Set_Font;  
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Name(const B_Activate: Boolean);
begin
       if B_Activate then  CB_Font_Name.OnChange := Action_Font_Name
                     else  CB_Font_Name.OnChange := nil;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Size(const B_Activate: Boolean);
begin
       if B_Activate then  CB_Font_Size.OnChange := Action_Font_Size
                     else  CB_Font_Size.OnChange := nil;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Try_to_Set_Font_Size(const i_Font_Size: Integer);
begin
       if ( (i_Font_Size>=c_Font_Min) AND (i_Font_Size<=c_Font_Max) ) = FALSE  then Exit;

       if Memo1.Font.Size <> i_Font_Size then try Memo1.Font.Size := i_Font_Size except end;

       if CB_Font_Size.Text <> IntToStr(i_Font_Size) then
       begin
             P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Size(False);
             try CB_Font_Size.ItemIndex := CB_Font_Size.Items.IndexOf( IntToStr(i_Font_Size) ) except end;
             P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Size(True);
       end;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Try_to_Set_Font_Name(const s_Font_Name: string);
begin
       if ( Length(s_Font_Name) > 0 ) = FALSE then Exit;

             if Memo1.Font.Name <> s_Font_Name then try Memo1.Font.Name := s_Font_Name except end;

       if CB_Font_Name.Text <> s_Font_Name then
       begin
             P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Name(False);
             try CB_Font_Name.ItemIndex := CB_Font_Name.Items.IndexOf( s_Font_Name ) except end;
             P_Activate_Event_Handler_Font_Name(True);
       end;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Size(const i_Font_Size: Integer);
begin
      if F_Current_Font_Size=i_Font_Size then Last_Loaded_Font_Size := i_Font_Size;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Save_Last_Loaded_Font_Name(const s_Font_Name: string);
begin
      if F_Current_Font_Name=s_Font_Name then Last_Loaded_Font_Name := s_Font_Name;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.Action_Font_Size(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
      if TryStrToInt(CB_Font_Size.Text,i) then P_Try_to_Set_Font_Size(i);
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.Action_Font_Name(Sender: TObject);
begin
       P_Try_to_Set_Font_Name(CB_Font_Name.Text) ;
end;
{=============================}
function TForm2.F_Current_Font_Size : Integer;
begin
       Result := Memo1.Font.Size;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
       P_Start;
end;
{=============================}
function TForm2.F_Current_Font_Name : String;
begin
       Result := Memo1.Font.Name;
end;
{=============================}
function TForm2.F_We_Must_Save_Font_Size : BOOLEAN;
begin
      Result := (    F_Current_Font_Size <> Default_Font_Size )
                OR
                (
                  (Last_Loaded_Font_Size <> F_Current_Font_Size)
                  AND
                  (Last_Loaded_Font_Size <> C_Error_Font_Size  )
                );
end;
{=============================}
function TForm2.F_We_Must_Save_Font_Name : BOOLEAN;
begin
      Result := (    F_Current_Font_Name <> Default_Font_Name )
                OR
                (
                  (Last_Loaded_Font_Name <> F_Current_Font_Name)
                  AND
                  (Last_Loaded_Font_Name <> C_Error_Font_Name  )
                );
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Init_Default_Values;
begin
  Default_Font_Name     := Memo1.Font.Name   ;
  Default_Font_Size     := Memo1.Font.Size   ;
  Last_Loaded_Font_Name := C_Error_Font_Name ;
  Last_Loaded_Font_Size := C_Error_Font_Size ;
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Make_List_of_Font_Name;
begin
     CB_Font_Name.Items.Assign(Screen.Fonts);
end;
{=============================}
procedure TForm2.P_Make_List_of_Font_Size;
var S : TStrings; i : Integer;
begin
     S := CB_Font_Size.Items; S.Clear;
     for i := c_Font_Min to c_Font_Max do S.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;
{=============================}


end.
```

Comment: should I also add a dfm-code for my forms ?

Comment: @ChrisJefferson If you wish.

Comment: Nevertheless I ask you to download this zip file and open my test project in your IDE and you'll see the sence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but there is very simple solution for saving and retrieving component configuration. You can save current configuration of components using WriteComponentRes :

```
var
  FS : TFileStream;
  Count: Byte;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Option.res',fmOpenWrite or fmCreate);
  try
    FS.WriteComponentRes(Form1.ClassName,Form1);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
  // Free all components on form 1
  for Count:= Form1.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
    Form1.Components[0].Free;
end;
```

And retrieve theme using ReadComponentRes method :

```
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  TempForm1: TForm1;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  // Free all components on form 1
  for Count:= Form1.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do
    Form1.Components[0].Free;

  FS := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Option.res',fmOpenRead);
  try
    TempForm1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
    FS.ReadComponentRes(Form1);
    Form1 := TempForm1;
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You casn also use TMemoryStream instead of TFileStream to store the configuration in byte array and save and retrieve it from database.